# Dynamic Textview is not fitting in the multiline

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm having an issue with my android application. I want to dynamically create 4 TableRows in a TableLayout. Each of this row will contain 1 TextView. I want the TextView like this:

```
 textview1
 textview2
 textview3
 textview4
```

in 4 different rows.

I am able to create the Tewtview dynamically but the sizes are not matching. For example if my first textview contains a big text, it appears to be in single text without being continued to the next line

I read a lot of similar questions but couldn't find the solution. Here is my layout file:

```
<Relativelayout>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/didyoudo"
android:layout_above="@+id/bardown" android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000"
android:scrollbarSize="12dip">

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/answertable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1" android:collapseColumns="2">


  </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Relativelayout/>
```

And this is how I'm generating the rows and textview dynamically

```
for (k =0; k< questionCount;k++ ) {
                    //tmpDict = trivialist.get(k);
                    Trivia trivia = trivialist.get(k);
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                    TableRow row1 = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                    TableRow row2 = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                    TableRow row3 = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                    TextView tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    TextView tv2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    TextView tv3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    TextView tv4 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                     desc = trivia.getAnswerDesc();
                     quizquestion = trivia.getStrQuestion();
                    tv1.setText("\n\t" + quizquestion);
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
                    tv1.setSingleLine(false);
                    tv1.setLines(2);
                    tv1.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                    tv1.setTextSize(15);
                    tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                            try {
                                //if the below value is null, it means that the selected answer is wrong 
                                // and enters to the else block
                                if (triviaDict.get("correctAnswer") != null) {
                                    String answer = (String) triviaDict.get("correctAnswer");
                                    tv2.setText("\n\t" + "You said: "+ answer + "\n");
                                    tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv2.setSingleLine(false);
                                    tv2.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                                    tv2.setTextSize(15);
                                    tv2.setLines(2);
                                    tv2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                                    tv3.setText("\t" +"That's Right."+ desc+"\n");
                                    tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv3.setSingleLine(false);
                                    tv3.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                                    tv3.setTextSize(15);
                                    tv3.setLines(2);
                                    tv3.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                                    tv4.setText("\t" + "_____________________________________" );
                                    tv4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv3.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                                    tv4.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                } else {
                                    String wronganswer = (String) triviaDict.get("selected");
                                    tv2.setText("\n\t" + "You said:"+ wronganswer +"\n" );
                                    tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv2.setTextSize(15);
                                    tv2.setLines(2);
                                    tv2.setSingleLine(false);
                                    tv2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                                    tv3.setText("\t" + "Actually," + desc +"\n");
                                    tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv3.setTextSize(15);
                                    tv3.setLines(2);
                                    tv3.setSingleLine(false);
                                    tv3.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                                    tv4.setText("\t" + "_____________________________________" );
                                    tv4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv3.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                                    tv4.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                                    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,10));
                tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,10));
                tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,10));


                    row.addView(tv1);
                    row1.addView(tv2);
                    row2.addView(tv3);
                    row3.addView(tv4);
                    answerTable.addView(row);
                    answerTable.addView(row1);
                    answerTable.addView(row2);
                    answerTable.addView(row3);

                }
```

But nothing is working perfect. This works for the 3rd textview but not for the 1st one. Don't know what is happening.

Can anybody tell me what to do.

**Update**

I do not have any problem with this code except that only tv3 gets proceeded to the next line on large text but not the tv1. 
I want tv1, tv2 and tv3 all to be continued in the next line in case of large text

Comment: Why are you using table layout instead of LL with vertical orientation

Comment: @Ankit, I want to dynamically create the rows containing textview. So I am using this, do you think with LL I can do this?

Comment: obviously,you can do it. with LL it is very easy to achieve, the only drawback is that you view hierarchy level increase.

Comment: @Ankit, I tried with this type of xml and and above java code <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/didyoudo"
 android:layout_above="@+id/bardown" android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000"
 android:scrollbarSize="12dip">
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/answertable"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

 </LinearLayout> 
 </ScrollView>

Comment: Instead of adding rows, I'm adding textviews to linear layout. But nothing is getting generated except the line i.e., tv4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I came up with some answer for this. First thing is I kept an integer count to fix how much characters to be fit in a single line. After that count the total no of characters in the string. Then divide the first integer count by total no of characters in the string. Then you will get an integer number. For my required, I added +2 for that integer number. Then set the lines of the textview to finally obtained number.

Thus, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Relativelayout>

<ScrollView 
android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/didyoudo"
android:layout_above="@+id/bardown" android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000"
android:scrollbarSize="12dip">

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/answertable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="0,*" >
  </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Relativelayout/>


****************************** JAVA code : ****************************

for (k =0; k< questionCount;k++ ) {
                    //tmpDict = trivialist.get(k);
                    Trivia trivia = trivialist.get(k);

                    TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

                    TextView tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    TextView tv2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    TextView tv3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    TextView tv4 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                     desc = trivia.getAnswerDesc();
                     quizquestion = trivia.getStrQuestion();

                    tv1.setText("\n\t" + quizquestion);
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
                    tv1.setSingleLine(false);
                    tv1.setLines(2);
                    tv1.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                    tv1.setTextSize(15);
                    tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                            try {
                                //if the below value is null, it means that the selected answer is wrong 
                                // and enters to the else block
                                if (triviaDict.get("correctAnswer") != null) {
                                    String answer = (String) triviaDict.get("correctAnswer");
                                    tv2.setText("\n\t" + "You said: "+ answer + "\n");
                                    tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv2.setSingleLine(false);
                                    tv2.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                                    tv2.setTextSize(15);
                                    tv2.setLines(2);
                                    tv2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                                    tv3.setText("\t" +"That's Right."+ desc+"\n");
                                    tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv3.setSingleLine(false);
                                    tv3.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                                    tv3.setTextSize(15);
                                    tv3.setLines(2);
                                    tv3.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                                    tv4.setText("\t" + "_____________________________________" );
                                    tv4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv3.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                                    tv4.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                } else {
                                    String wronganswer = (String) triviaDict.get("selected");
                                    tv2.setText("\n\t" + "You said:"+ wronganswer +"\n" );
                                    tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv2.setTextSize(15);
                                    tv2.setLines(2);
                                    tv2.setSingleLine(false);
                                    tv2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                                    tv3.setText("\t" + "Actually," + desc +"\n");
                                    tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv3.setTextSize(15);
                                    tv3.setLines(2);
                                    tv3.setSingleLine(false);
                                    tv3.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                                    tv4.setText("\t" + "_____________________________________" );
                                    tv4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv3.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                                    tv4.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                                    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,10));
                tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,10));
                tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,10));
                tv4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,10));


                    row.addView(tv1);
                    row.addView(tv2);
                    row.addView(tv3);
                    row.addView(tv4);
                    answerTable.addView(row);


                }
```

Comment: only difference is with stretchColumns right? This is not working for me :(